# javascript how to load an script or data like google without ajax on any event

Tags: javascript, html

If i do this code

```
<script>
    $('<img></img>').attr('src', 'someimage.jpg').appendTo($('#div'));
</script>
<div id="div"></div>
```

I can see `GET htpp://somedomain.ext/someimage.jpg` in Net Panel in Firebug.

I think google autocomplete also works pretty much the same way, since there are no asynchronous request, nothing can be seen on firebug console.

Now, is there any object (like img) that i could send `http` request to some domain for loading data like google.

**UPDATE::**

I HONESTLY DON'T SEE A THING IN XHR TAB IN NET PANEL.

WHY AM I SEEING REQEST MADE IN JS TAB IN NET PANEL.

Please correct me if i have misunderstood.

Comment: you are wrong - google autocomplete works with XHR requests. you can see them in the network tab in firebug. but generally i dont understand your question

Comment: @Shree i was looking how could i make `request` like google does on autocomplete

Comment: I think you are wrong, google sends async request on each keystroke. In FireBug if you click the "NET" tab you will see them

Comment: try something like `jQuery.get()` explained here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: @felixsigl I am able to see all my `XHR` request on firebug console, but for google, why can't i see? I can only see it in `js` tab of `Net` panel in firebug

Comment: @experimentX -- google is using a script request (aka JSONP) rather than an XHR request.  I presume this is because they are using a public API that can be used by external web sites where JSONP would be necessary.

Comment: @tvanfosson thank you. I guess that it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) method or one if the convenient front-ends for it: [post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post), [get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get), [load](http://api.jquery.com/load), or [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript). There's an entire plugin written around the AJAX calls in jQuery for [autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete).  I'll note that if you are planning to get data from server outside the domain of your web page, you'll need to use [JSONP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) against an API that supports it due to the same origin policy which disallows AJAX requests to other domains.  When using JSONP as the result type, jQuery silently turns `ajax`, `post`, and `get` requests into script requests, i.e., adds a script tag with the url and url-encoded parameters to the data source and expects a script back that executes a callback with the returned data.

Comment: sir can i make request to `JSONP` without `XHR` request .i.e without being seen on console.

Comment: certainly they are loading script without using ajax means that there something doing this what is this (object). And also how can i be able to do so.

Comment: @experimentX - Yes and no.  It won't be an XHR request, but it will show up as a regular request for a script.